# How can I change the formula of the cell according to the value of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If Cell A1 = X, Cell B2 = sum(A1+A2)
If Cell A1 = Y, Cell B2 = sum(A1+A3)

is excel capable of doing this? if not using VBA

Answer (score 1):

let A1 have a value of 5
let D2 have a value of 5(Where this would represent your Y.
then B1 have a value of =if(A1=D2,SUM(A1:A3),SUM(A1:A2))

Comment: In your formula, if A1=D2, your sum would include A2, which is not what the OP wants. I suggest you change the colon to a comma: `=if(A1=D2,SUM(A1,A3),SUM(A1,A2))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in B2,

```
=sum(A1, if(a1="X", A2, if(a1="Y", A3, "")))
```

Of course you cannot get any numerical value from *X* or *Y* so using A1 as part of the sum is pretty useless but you can modify for you own purposes.

Comment: Note that if A1 is neither X nor Y, the formula will produce a #VALUE!, which may or may not be what the OP wants.